# Fix wrong hard drive partition size after install

Tags: partition

I'm not 100% sure how to phrase this:
While installing Win 2008 the screen asked me where to install the OS
(I only have 1 hard drive)
It said: 2 GB was partioned for the OS
and 160 GB were remainining.
I wanted to create a fresh partition just for the OS 
So I added a new one with 10 GB and continued.

However now its looks like I only have a single 10 GB hard drive.
Other than re-installing the OS again, how can I get the other 150 GB to appear as another disk drive?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the rest of the space as a seperate drive, then:

1. Right-Click 'My Computer'
2. Select 'Manage'
3. Navigate to 'Disk Management'
4. Locate the free space and right-click
5. Select 'New Partition'

On the other hand if you want the slack space as part of your C: drive, right-click the existing C: partition and select 'Expand'.

Comment: you can also resize with disk manager   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637755.aspx

Comment: In Win7 you can Grow the Disk from the same management console. It was WinXP that you have to use GParted for.

Comment: Thanks guys, good to learn that's been enhanced in Win7/2008